# Radon-Nikodym for continuous time processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, levy-processes

Likelihood theory for statistical inference concerning stochastic processes in continuous time are well used. How ever i've found no real literature concerning the fundamentals.

**What is know from elementary stochastic**

Let $X$ be a random variable mapping to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{F}^{X}=X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
Assume there is a measure $Q$, such that 
$P_{|\mathcal{F}^{X}}\ll Q_{|\mathcal{F}^{X}}$.
we define the radon nikodym density 
$$
f(\mathcal{F}^{X})=\frac{dP_{|\mathcal{F}^{X}}}{dQ_{|\mathcal{F}^{X}}}
$$
If this is case  for the pushforward measures it holds $P^{X}\ll Q^{X}$, where $Q^{X}(B)=Q(A)$ and $A:=X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}^{X}$.
We can define a randon nikodym density
$$
f(X)=\frac{dP^{X}}{dQ^{X}}
$$
Now the transformation theorem states, that
$$
f(\mathcal{F}^{X})(\omega)=f(X(\omega))\quad Q-a.s.
$$

**Question**

This question is now concerning stochastic processes.
Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be defined $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ with $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$.
Assume $P_{\mathcal{F}_t}\ll Q_{\mathcal{F}_t}$.
We can define again
$$
f(\mathcal{F}_t)=\frac{dP_{|\mathcal{F_t}}}{dQ_{|\mathcal{F}_t}} \tag1
$$
Can we conclude that,
$$
f(\mathcal{F}_t)(\omega)=\frac{dP_{|\mathcal{F_t}}}{dQ_{|\mathcal{F}_t}}(\omega)=\frac{dP^{(X_s(\omega))_{s\leq t}}}{dQ^{(X_s(\omega))_{s\leq t}}}=f((X_s(\omega)_{s\leq t})
$$
holds? What can we say about this situation? 
What does this mean? Are the pushforward measures really induced by the whole sample path $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$? 
Or do we say that (1) can be expressed almost sureley as a function of the sample path $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$?